# ASP.NET MVC - Routes and UrlHelper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, urlhelper

I have the following route

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "GigDayListings",                                   // Route name
    "gig/list/{year}/{month}/{day}",                    // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Gig", action = "List" },
    new
    {
        year = @"^[0-9]+$",
        month = @"^[0-9]+$",
        day = @"^[0-9]+$"
    }  // Parameter defaults
);
```

When I visit the URL

```
gig/list/2009/01/01
```

This route matches perfectly and my action is called.

Inside my view I have a helper which does the following:

```
var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(ViewContext);
string url = urlHelper.RouteUrl(ViewContext.RouteData.Values);
```

The string generated is:

```
http://localhost:3539/gig/list?year=2005&month=01&day=01
```

Why is it not

```
http://localhost:3539/gig/list/2005/01/01
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The url I visit is:

http://localhost:3539/gig/list/2005/01/01

Sorry about the typo!

Answer (score 9):

I think your problem is that you didn't specify the route name in your call. Try to use

```
UrlHelper.RouteUrl(**"GigDayListings"**, ViewContext.RouteData.Values);
```

overload with route name.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that when you supply gig/list/2008/01/01 that it is actually using the GigDayListings route? Maybe it's using a different one